# How to verify only the elements names in a dictionary object?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have a VERY big dictionary in python and when I type dict.items(dic_name) it shows up so many stuff (matrix, vectors, etc). I just would like to see the elements names. What should I do?

For example when I have a list I type names (`my.list`) and it just displays the list elements name.  Is there a command like that in Python?

Comment: how about `dic_name.keys()` ?

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you only keys, ask for keys, not items :

```
my_dict.keys()
```

If you strictly need it to be a list you can do :

```
my_list = list(my_dict.keys())
```

Now if you want to iterate through them:

in python 2:

```
for k in my_dict.iterkeys():
    do_something_with(k)
```

in python 3:

```
for k in my_dict.keys():
    do_something_with(k)
```